# Load content in a div without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all I warn you i am new in HTML development...

I am creating a website using Bootstrap. I have some buttons on the left as you can see in the screenshot and I want to content on the right to change without having to load the whole page.

[image: Website structure]

Any help here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: study some ajax tutorials

Comment: Have you looked at Ajax :)

Comment: Ajax is only necessary if you want to pull content from server.  If you are going to code the content right into the HTML and you just want the content that's displayed to change based on which button you press, Ajax would be unnecessary.

Comment: @z416175 I am fine putting the code directly in the html no need for server here. How can i do it then using your approach?

Comment: You are expected to put some effort into the task before you ask a question here.  Otherwise you will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Maybe this simple thing give you an idea on how to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/80mdsk9h/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use JavaScript, which is the standard programming language that ships with all modern web browsers. In JavaScript, there is an API called the DOM (Document Object Model) which represents the current page as an object. You can use that API to change the text contained in the div tag.

[Here is the W3Schools page on the DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

There are a few JavaScript libraries that try to abstract and simplify DOM manipulation. The most famous is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Yes. Check out jQuery, it'll be quicker to wrap your head around, and trying to accomplish what you want will be a good introduction.  Hint: you'll need to listen for click events on the buttons and manipulate the css display property of the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using AngularJS or any MVC framework/library. These might be a little heavy-handed for something simple, but they'll help achieve what you're looking for. Pretty good to learn these anyway as they're in high demand.

[Here's](https://angularjs.org/) AngularJS's homepage with docs and tutorials. You'd want to look at information on routing view templates using the ngView module, or you can use ui-router, created by Angular's UI team (my personal favorite) for nested views.

PS: Stay away from W3Schools 
http://www.w3fools.com/